# Regex url rewrite for short URL'S

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been having a small issue, I have a short URL system that gets used like so:

```
domain.com/KeiBf3
```

That goes to

```
domain.com/url.php?u=KeiBf3
```

Yet I also have other stuff such as

```
domain.com/file.ext
```

And I keep adding stuff, but since my regex is made in a way so anything (such as file.ext) gets called to:

```
domain.com/url.php?u=file.ext
```

And my temporary solution is to manually add a url rewrite rule for each file that I use, letting them pass and not get called into the main redirect. I can't seem to fix this issue, maybe limiting anything that has a "." character in it, to let it pass, here is my current rewrite rule, can anyone help me out?

```
"^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" => "/url.php?u=$1"
```

I'm trying to make it so this does not also grab "." characters, and make the ending "/" at the end of a URL, optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /url.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```